# Auto-resize multiple Forms rendered on Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this Form with Panels. This Form has three Panels.
One Panel is collapsible and acts as a sidebar, the other one sits at the top and is there for showing title, the last one is the placeholder for the Forms being opened by clicking on one of the items being catered in Panel one.

Now what I want to do is resize (grow and shrink) the size (width only) of the placeholder Panel and the Form that is opened on the Panel according to the state of Panel one, which could either be expanded or collapsed. The dock is not working.

[image]

Comment: Can you share an image what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You should explain what do you mean by *resize (grow and shrink) (...) the form that is opened on the panel*. If the Container `Panel` resizes, what should happen to the embedded Form? Become *smaller*? When you embed an object in a `ScrollableControl` (the `container Panel`), its scroll bars appear (if `AutoScroll` is set to true, that is). You don't want the scroll bars? Something else?

Comment: @Mino, check the image please.

Comment: @Jimi, like I said, I want the container panel and the embedded form to resize - grow in width when sidebar is collapsed and shrink when sidebar is expanded. As for scrollbars, they are not and never will be there.

Comment: Ok, no Scroll Bars. Now, (...) *embedded form to resize - grow in width when sidebar is collapsed and shrink when sidebar is expanded*. Did you mean the opposite? Shrink when the container is collapsed?. If a Form is embedded, its visible size depends on the size of the container. Do you mean that you want to shrink the embedded Form **Content** (maybe a PictureBox control)? If not, resizing the container is enough. Maybe you should also explain how the embedding is obtained (if the Form is actually embedded).

Comment: @Jimi, nope. I mean exactly what I said. The container form should grow in width when sidebar is collapsed and vice versa.

Comment: Ah, my bad, it's the *SideBar* that is shrinked.The arrow inside Panel 3 got stuck in the wrong way. If both SideBar and Container (Panel 3) are docked, the Container resizes automatically. What is then the problem with the guest Form? Did you embed it or just opened it?

Comment: `panel3.Controls.Clear();
            SearchECN searchECN = new SearchECN();
            searchECN.TopLevel = false;
            searchECN.Location = new Point(25, searchECN.Location.Y);
            panel3.Controls.Add(searchECN);
            searchECN.Show();`

Comment: _Did you embed it or just opened it?_ What's the difference?

Comment: Nope, docking won't work, like I said. I have to be able to collapse the sidebar too. It won't collapse if it is docked.

Comment: @Jimi, When the sidebar is collapsed, it disappears, which is exactly as desired. The emerging space should then be occupied by the container panel and the form that is open on it. And when the sidebar is expanded again, the container panel and the form being contained should slide back and resize too to occupy the new width.

Comment: *Embedding* is what you just wrote. You set it to `TopLevel = false` and set `searchECN.Parent = panel3`, then you are *embedding *  it. I don't see the problem. Look at this, for example (made it just now)  [Embedded Form](https://i.imgur.com/JXrmDmY.gifv). Should it look like this?

Comment: @Jimi, yes. Exactly.

Comment: As of now, the sidebar is collapsing and the container panel is shifting to the left too. But the container panel is not occupying the new width.

Comment: Because it's not docked. I'll write you a couple of notes on how that Form you saw in that animation is obtained.

Comment: @Jimi, I did dock it. But it starts getting shaky like a _sci-fi anomaly_ and doesn't collapse when I collapse it because of being docked and collapsing at the same time. Maybe I am doing it wrong. Looking forward to see your notes.

Comment: Also, the example animation is not resizing the embedded form. Just took a closer look. Otherwise, the sliding functionality is already working.

Comment: Yes, the Form is resized. I've already asked you this. Do you want to resize the embedded Form **Content**? Because this all depends on the embedded Form original design. All of its parts have to resize themselves (because they are contained in LayoutPanels or because the inner containers are docked or anchored to achieve this). If the original design does not anticipate this behaviour, there's nothing you can do about it. Well, you could take a screenshot of it :)

Comment: _Yes, the Form is resized._ Resized or relocated?

Comment: `private void panContainer_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e) { Rectangle rect = panContainer.ClientRectangle; rect.Inflate(-3, -3); frmGuest.Size = rect.Size; }`. It resizes when the host panel resizes. But you can't see its borders, so...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some clarifications, it appears that the desidered layout and behaviour of the described Form is similar to this sample disposition:

A `WinForms` `Form` is *embedded* in another `Form`, and placed inside a `Panel`.
This Guest `Form` is stripped of its `TopLevel` coat-of-arms and *parented* to central Panel, as shown in this graphic example:

[image]

How do you dock these `Panels` to get this layout:

The **Green Panel** stays on top of the Form.
The **DarkGray Panel** lays on the left hand side of the Form.
The **Gray Panel** occupies the remaining space.

- Insert three Panels on a Form container.
- The **Green Panel** needs to maintain its position, it will never change:

  - Right click → SendToBack (`!important` :).
  - Dock → Top.
- The **DarkGray Panel** is positioned under the Green Panel, on the left side of the Form. It needs to resize itself when needed, but will never cover the Green Panel:

  - Dock → Left
- The **Gray Panel** needs to occupy the remaining space. It needs to resize itself when needed, but it will never cover Green Panel or Dark Gray Panel:

  - Right click → BringToFront  (`!important`)
  - Dock → Center

The highest priority when docking, is assigned to the element which has the lowest z-order in the stack: the **Green Panel**, here.
The lowest priority is assigned to element with the highest z-order: the Gray Panel, which will then *shrink and stretch* among all other elements with higher priority (following the z-order).

How to embed the Form:

The easy part. It's a Form in our Project, no need to perform any magic to keep it alive when re-parented:
(This is just for 1 Form. With more Forms, you'll need something like a `List<Control>`:

```
//Define here the Form which will be embedded
[Your Form Class] EmbeddedForm;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmbeddedForm = new [Your Form Class]() {
        TopLevel = false,
        Parent = panContainer,
        Location = new Point(4, 4),
        Enabled = true
    };
    EmbeddedForm.Show();
}

private void buttonShrink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Maybe insert a classic dotted mini-button to re-inflate the sidebar when needed
    panelSideBar.Width = 6;
}

private void panelContainer_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = panelContainer.ClientRectangle;
    rect.Inflate(-3, -3);
    EmbeddedForm.Size = rect.Size;
}
```

If you allow your Container Panel to `AutoScroll` its content, the `Resize` event is not necessary.

**Edit:**
A PasteBin of the complete source code of the Form in sample graphics: 
[Embedded Forms](https://pastebin.com/cQg8dNGT)