# How do I resize a UserControl to fit in a container in a windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to fit a user control into a panel in another form. I have tried docking and auto size but nothing seems to work.

[image: Main Form]

I am trying to fit this into the above panel, but its hiding the buttons. How to resize it so it will scale to the panel size?

[image: UserControl.cs]

Comment: Usercontrol is docking properly, but you also need to apply dock to controls inside that user control, _ex : apply full docking to the textbox etc._

Comment: Insert those `Buttons` in a separate `Panel`. I left some notes [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471230/auto-resize-multiple-windows-forms-being-rendered-on-panel?answertab=active#tab-top) about docking multiple controls (`Panels`. mostly) in a parent container. See if it helps.

Comment: Docking always worked better for me then anchors. But the problem is the controls have to be in the correct Z-Order. So it might be needed to do a `BringToFront()` on your panel so it does not overlaps the buttons. Its not clear to me though what your setup is. Is the panel you want to dock containing buttons or is the panel you want to drop it on containing buttons ? Or what is exact what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Before docking the user control you need to make sure control's of user control doesn't get messy when resized. And for that you to need set right values to controls of user control anchor properties. after that you can this code below to dock it.

```
userControlName ctrl = new userControlName();
panel1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

or you can do similar in controlAdded event of panel

```
foreach (Control ctrl in panel1.Controls)
{
ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

**Edit:** now i'm able to see pictures. you need to set

**textbox** to dock left and resize it

**button2** anchor to top,right

**button1** anchor to bottom,right

Answer (score 1):

Use SplitContainer control instead of panel, it will solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Anchor` property of the Panel, set it to "All" or "Bottom, Top, Left, Right". It will keep the same spacing with the container border, i.e. if you make the container smaller, it will become smaller, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A `TableLayoutPanel` would do the trick here.

On your `UserControl` put a `TableLayoutPanel` as the first control and set its `Dock` property to `Fill`.

Add an extra row to the `TableLayoutPanel` so you have 2 columns and 3 rows. Put your `Textbox` into the top left column, set `Multiline` to true and then set `Dock` to `Fill`. Find the `RowSpan` property and set it to 3.

Add your buttons to the right hand column, one in the first row and one in the second row. Don't set the `Dock` properties on these. Just set any extra margins you would need.

Finally open the Column/Row edit window for the `TableLayoutPanel` and set the Columns like this:

[image: Column settings]

And then set the Rows like this:

[image: Row settings]

Press Ok to exit the Column/Row styles window and your `UserControl` should now look like this:

[image: Final layout]

Should you want more spacing between the `Buttons` or a gap around the `TextBox` make sure to set the `Margin` properties on each of the controls until you have the layout you're after.

Now, when you place your new `UserControl` on to a design surface and resize it you'll find that the buttons no longer get obscured by the textbox.

You can, of course, play around with the number of columns/rows as you see fit until you get the layout you want.

I would suggest not setting your rows/columns to `AutoSize` until they contain a control otherwise the row/column will disappear from the design view and you will have to set the row/column from the `Cell`, `Row`, `Column` attached properties of the control you want to place.