# Scaling Controls on winforms on resizing form and window

Tags: winforms, button, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

Hello I am deisgning a form as shown in the image. It works fine but i have issues on maximizing and resizing window and form. I tried Dock, Anchor but the gridview comes on the top and the other controls on the tabcontrol are not visible. What can i do so that i am able to access all controls on resizing and maximizing. Please help!

[image]

Comment: You could have specified what anchoring you're using. In the current layout, your `DataGridView` could be anchored to all sides. The `Button` right below the `DGV`, to `Bottom/Right`. The `Label` on the bottom/left to `Bottom/Left` etc. You could also use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) to define specific layout positions. When a `TLP` cell is resized, it resizes its content.

Comment: I had used Anchor top left for gridview and Dock fill for Gridview and Tabcontrol. Is TablelayoutPanel a better option i tried that too. but resizing still doesnt happen. :(

Comment: Your `TabControl` should be Docked (`DockStyle.Fill`). The other controls as I described. Try that. Some [suggestions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471230/auto-resize-multiple-windows-forms-being-rendered-on-panel?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Wow that worked!!! Thanks a lot!!! Have a great weekend!