# How to add GroupBoxes to a TabPage in order?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, dock, groupbox

I have a `List<Category>` and a `TabPage`. For each `Category` I want to add a `GroupBox` to the `TabPage`. Each `GroupBox` should come below the previous one.

Here is what I have tried:

```
foreach (Category category in Categories)
{
    var groupBox = new GroupBox
    {
        Dock = DockStyle.Top
        Text = Category.Name,
    };

    page.Controls.Add(groupBox);
}
```

The problem is that the `Dock = DockStyle.Top` "pushes" all existing `GroupBox`es down, and put the new one on top of all the others, and as a result, the `GroupBox`es are shown in reverse.

I thought of adding a `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `TabPage` but it seems a bit ugly. Is there a way of doing this without adding dummy controls?

Thanks!

Comment: The child order matters to decide on the docking order.  It is not very intuitive, most programmers think it is backwards.  You need to add `page.BringToFront()` after the Add() call to get what you want.  Wrapping it with Suspend/ResumeLayout is advisable.

Comment: @HansPassant - `page.BringToFront()` or `groupBox.BringToFront()`?

Comment: Right, groupbox.

Comment: @HansPassant - It works. Please write it as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: Some related notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471230/auto-resize-multiple-windows-forms-being-rendered-on-panel?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @HansPassant - also, would you suspend the layout of the `Form` itself (highest in the controls hierarchy) or the layout of the `TabPage` (lowest in the controls hierarchy)?

Comment: Technically it depends on the container control type and its AutoSizeMode property.  But neither TabPage nor TabControl have that feature so the tabpage is good enough.