# How to dock panels to fill the entire form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm using vb.net 2017.  I want to put some panels and dock them in order to create a configuration like in the attached image:

[image]

So these panels must be docked and occupies the entire form. 
I've tried several docking mode , also I used the Send to back / Bring to to front but I can't do like I want.

How can I do it?

Comment: See [these notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471230/auto-resize-multiple-windows-forms-being-rendered-on-panel?answertab=active#tab-top) about docking Panels in a container.

Comment: TableLayoutPanels are great for this kind of thing, have you tried using one of those? They make it very easy to control the layout and resizing ratio of your panels, you would just use the TableLayoutPanel to control the size of each area and leave all the child controls' dockstyle set to fill

Comment: Place the bottom panel on first, dock bottom.  Place the left panel on next, dock left.  Place the right panel on last, dock fill.

Comment: @LarsTech I've tried does not work ,

Comment: "Does not work" does not help.  My instructions were on a blank form, and it does work.

Comment: @LarsTech the problem is that I already have these panels and  other control inside them  in an existing form , and I want to arrange like this without deleting and adding again. Yes , on an new empty form your instructions works.

Comment: Set the three panels to the dock style I specified, then play with the BringToFront methods of the panels until you get it right.  Should just have to bring the left-docked panel to the front to make it work.  Alternatively, use the menu "View" - "Other Windows" - "Document Outline" to adjust the z-order.

Comment: @Larstech I've tried , but the left panel fill the left part of the form until the bottom of the form. I've tried Bring to front for the bottom panel , but doesn't work.

Comment: I said to bring-to-front the left panel.

Comment: Order matters a lot.  First dock to the bottom, then to the left, then fill.  If the order is wrong then it is going to look different.  Right-click and bring to front or send to back or just delete and do it over.

Comment: Let's start like this : On the blank form, create a panel and set its dock property to TopLeft, create another panel and set its dock property to TopRight, then resize the panels to suit your needs and add colors.

Comment: The easiest way to help with the z-order is to view the Document Outline and move the panels up/down in the container (in this case, the container is the form).

Comment: @Adriano - I use a combo of Table Layout Panels and Panels to achieve this kind of effect.

Comment: Use the `Document Outline` window (found in view/other windows) to move the panels to the correct Z order. Its as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do, add a TableLayoutPanel to the form and set Dock to Fill.

Then I would add some rows and columns to it so I could combine them to produce the results.  Based on what I see it looks like you should end up with 5 columns of 20% and 4 rows of 25%.

Then drag a Panel to the top left cell of the TableLayoutPanel.
Set its:

```
.Column = 0
.ColumnSpan = 2
.Row = 0
.RowSpan = 3
.Dock = Fill
```

Follow this procedure and add two more panels.  One will start at row 0, column 2 and the other at row 3 column 0.

You might need to play around with the numbers to achieve the desired results.  When you get what you want you can set the margins of all of the panels to 0.

I use background colors on all the panels so I can see what it looks like while setting this up.