# Making a User Control that is in two pieces

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I am creating a collapsible panel control that is comprised of a clickable label docked at the top with an up/down arrow inside and a panel below it that is set to fill the rest of the control no matter the size.

I've also added code to make the control editable at design time.

`<Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", GetType(IDesigner))> _`

I plan to have multiple "versions" of this control that will behave differently. For instance;

- One filled only with dynamically created check boxes that will keep a running list of what's checked.
- Another that contains manually or dynamically added radio buttons.
- Another that is manually designed, etc

So each of these versions will be a new control that contains the original.

However I am running into an issue. When I add controls to this User Control like a tablelayoutplanel and set them to Dock.Fill. At design time they look fine with the added control being below the label but then once the application runs the Control inside fills to overlap the label and when the execution stops the change is also reflected in the design version.

So I am trying to figure out if it's possible to make a user control that is made up of multiple separate "parts";

- The label which would be inaccessible to the designer.
- The container panel below which would... contain all the things and be accessible at design time.

Barring that is there a way to override Dock.Fill so that its top position starts at X since I know how tall my label is? I'd rather avoid having to do code that resizes all the things since I have no way of knowing how many things may or may not wind up in a manually crafted one in the future.

I've tried looking up examples of collapsible panels but so far the ones I've found all either cause designer and code errors when I migrate them from the older versions of VS they were built in or they are in C#.

Plus they don't really have the look I'm trying to achieve. Which is

[image: Collapsible Panel]

If either of those can't be done please let me know so I can try and figure out a different approach to what I'm trying to achieve which basically amounts to; A thing that starts off the size of a label and opens/closes showing dock.fill container that has controls inside it when open and doesn't step over the label.

Thank you.

Edit: [Added a quick video to show the behavior.](https://youtu.be/mYwAhJTPVIk)

Comment: Try to add a Panel to the UC that acts as container for the controls you add (instead of dropping the new controls directly on the UC surface). This Panel could be anchored to all sides and positioned right below the Label. Also, read the notes here: [auto-resize multiple windows forms being rendered on panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476266/7444103) about the docking behaviour + some hints.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll have a read through what you've linked, though as I mentioned in the post there is already a Panel control below the labels, docked to fill. But on execution it seems to be treating the user control as one big object rather than two separate ones.

Comment: You can have a Panel container **Docked** (below the Label). But, in this case, the Label must be inside another container (another Panel) docked to TOP. See, in the notes I linked, the layout machanics when docking controls. A Label is to be considered a *static* object not a *top level* one.

Comment: I've put both my labels in a panel, docked said panel to top, sent it to back so it has the lowest Z set my second panel to fill which makes it take up the remainin space below panel 1. Compiled. Put the control in a new contol set it to fill , put a tabellayout panel inside the "second panel" of the control, set it to fill and again in design it stops at the borders of the "second panel" but in debug it fills the whole control and once exited it's also filling the whole control until i change docking.  I'm going to make a vid to better explain what is happening.

Comment: added the video in the original post, though the behavior has changed  a bit, now it alternates between what I've described or just shoving the controls behind the object that is supposed to contain them.

Comment: [UserControl_Slider](https://imgur.com/a/arcxRYR). I told you **anchored**.

Comment: [Nope](https://i.imgur.com/HkB1ZMR.mp4) Also, dock disable anchored and vice versa

Comment: [Additionally weird](https://i.imgur.com/KmJlcce.mp4)

Comment: It looks like the resizing logic is faulty here. Try this one (made in 10 minutes, so it's what it is) [SliderPanel on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fo8FD1HNYUvrqDwNQM4tNA8Tz4qS5quW).

Comment: I thought there was a disconnect somewhere and now I know where it is. The object I am adding the tablelayoutpanel to is the Compiled version of the slider panel. I am using that new control to make new controls.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about making a control that is multiple parts. Best example I can give is Tab Control, It's made up of two components The Control which houses the tabs and the Pages which contain stuff. You can't put controls on the tabs portion of the Tab Control and if you dock a control inside a Page it stays inside the page, it does not spill over.

Answer (score 0):

So I was sort of able to achieve the effect I wanted but I had to go a completely different route which I'm not really happy about.

I now have two controls as part of my Slide Panel control.

- SlidePanelLabel
- SlidePanelPanel

SlideLabelLabel sits at the top of the parent it is dropped into and if clicked will grow and shrink said parent based on parent.maximumsize.height without actually affecting itself.

SlidePanelPanel is just an empty panel control with some overrides that deal with a few irksome situations with scroll bars.

---

On the one side it means I can use the "Label" to grow and shrink other things if I want and I might expand on it in order to give it some directional functionality.

On the other I really wanted to figure out how to make a thing that can "spawn" an object that has designer functionality in an area around/inside itself like a Tab Control. Where the Tab area will block you from adding controls to it but the pages will not.

Basically have SlidePanelLabel spawn a SlidePanelPanel whenever it is added to something and have that spawned SlidePanelPanel be able to have controls dropped on it.

So unless anyone has insight on the latter you can consider this question closed I guess.

I do want to thank Jimi for trying to help and for the useful info on dock and anchoring and such.