# Auto resize control based on space left by other control

Tags: winforms

Inside a fixed size UserControl, I have two controls stacked one on top of the other. Both controls use all the width of the containing control. The one on top has variable height. I would like the one at the bottom to have its height automatically adapt to the changes in height of the one on top to have it occupy all the (variable) remaining space left by the one on top

Tried various "Dock" options without success

Comment: All controls have a [Resize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resize) event. You can use it to synchronize the size of another control. Set the Control's `Dock = DockStyle.Top`. Or anchor Left/Top/Right. But, what do you mean with *one on top of the other*? From the description, it looks like the two controls occupy different sections of the same container.

Comment: That's what I was hoping to be able to avoid: compute and set the size manually on resize event :-)

Comment: if I do that one control occupies all the space. The other is not wisible.

Comment: Or set the one that you resize to `Dock = Top` (right-click and `SendToBack()`) and the other to `Dock = Fill`. This one is simpler.

Comment: Read the notes about docking here: [auto-resize multiple windows forms being rendered on panel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476266/7444103).

Comment: that last comment (before the one about reading the notes) seems to do the trick: thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Another option is to use a TableLayoutPanel with one column and two rows.  The first row would be set to AutoSize.  The second row would be set to 100%.  The control in the second row would set Dock to Fill.  Now when you change the size of the control in the first row, the first row will autosize, then the second row will adjust and the control in it will change as well.